# How to display values of the 2 inputs in the above field?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to react, and i've gone through this link "[reactjs - Dropdown select with 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49560671/reactjs-dropdown-select-with-2-fields)" here my objective is i have to get the min value and max value in the rate range field. Instead of  tag i've used input tag, in order to get the min and Max values.

I'm trying to show the min value left hand side and Max value in the right hand side, but when we click on the min and Max input then the values are displaying in the left hand side and I have to get the min value and max value in the rate range field.

```
import "./sample.css"
import React from "react";
import {List, Input, Form} from "semantic-ui-react"

class Select extends React.Component {

    state = {
      activeMenu: 'min',
      open: true,
      min: '',
      max: ''
    };

    toggleMenu = e => {
      this.setState({
        activeMenu: e.target.name
      });
    };

    toggleOpen = () => {
      this.setState( prevState => {
        return { open: !prevState.open }
      });
    };

    getMenuOptions = () => {
      let options = [];
      switch(this.state.activeMenu){
        case 'min': {
          options = ['$40,000','$60,000','$80,000','$100,000','$120,000','$140,000', '$160,000', '$180,000'];
          break;
        }
        case 'max': {
          options = ['$60,000','$80,000','$100,000','$120,000','140,000','$160,000','$180,000'];
          break;
        }
      }
      return options.map( (option, i) => {
        return (
          <List key={i} onClick={this.handleSelect.bind(this, this.state.activeMenu, option)}>
            {option}
          </List>
        )
      });
    };

    handleSelect = (menu, value) => {
      this.setState({
        [menu]: value
      });
    };

    render() {
      const { open, min, max, activeMenu } = this.state;
      const menuOptions = this.getMenuOptions();
      return(
        <div className="myRange">
          <Input icon='caret down' onClick={this.toggleOpen} placeholder='Rate Range'/>

          {open && (
            <div>
             <Form>
              <Form.Group className="myRange" >
                        <Form.Input placeholder='Min' name="min" value={min} onFocus={this.toggleMenu} />
                        &mdash;
                        <Form.Input className = "myValues"placeholder='Max' name="max" value={max} onFocus={this.toggleMenu}/>

                    </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
              <div>
                <ul className={activeMenu}>
                  {menuOptions}
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }export default Select;
```

Could you please help me on the above query

Comment: include your css too please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
ul.max {
  float: right;
}
```

to your sample.css. That's why the max value is not displaying on right side.

Link to a working example i made - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-mupej

EDIT: You want something like this? https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-9rzow

EDIT: Is this what you want?
https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-e25on

Comment: Thanks it is displaying in the right side. There is another problem. I want to retrieve both Min and Max value in Range input once it get displayed in Min and Max input.

Comment: @Chandan can you clarify more? The lowest min to lowest max value? Something like that?

Comment: @Chandan I added another sanbox link. Check and see if that's what you want? I changed the way your options array are taken to make the values in state dynamic. So that if you change the values of your array then other stuff with change too. Instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: If this helped you then upvote and accept this as an answer. :)

Comment: I want the range should get updated when we will give inputs to Min and Max value. Initially it should show only "placeholder = rate range" content.

Comment: When we give the values in min and max field as $40,000 and $60,000 then the **Rate Range** should be $40,000-$60,000. I want in this way

Comment: @Chandan i have updated my answer. See if that's what you want?